# Neither builtin power function nor np.power works

Tags: python, numpy

I've got the following simple two things given:

```
n = 2.01
array = np.array([-0.3700708 , -0.41282227, -0.25959961])
```

Now I want each of the array elements to be raised to the power of `(n-1.)`. So I tried the following:

```
>>> array**(n-1.)
array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
>>> np.power(array, (n-1.))
array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
```

If I take out each element and raise it to the power of `(n-1.)`, it works fine. Where's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around - convert `array` to complex

```
In [83]: (array+0j)**(n-1)  # or array.astype('complex')
Out[83]: 
array([-0.36622949-0.01150923j, -0.40898407-0.01285284j,
       -0.25599573-0.00804499j])
```

Apparently the `**` responds to the `dtype` of the array, producing complex values when the dtype is complex, but throwing up its hands in failure when it is float.  Details probably can be found buried in the C code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the results are *complex values*, e.g.

```
  -0.3700708 ** 1.01 == -0.366229 - 0.011509i
```

Edit: When computing the value at **Wolfram Alpha** do (raise negative into power)

```
  (-0.3700708) ** 1.01
```

and not (first raise into power, then negate)

```
  -0.3700708 ** 1.01
```

Comment: I get the negative, but very much real, [-0.366...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-0.37^1.01) as result from both Python and Wolfram Alpha. I also see no intuitive reason why it *should* be complex. Care to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `x ** 1.01 = x ** (101 / 100) == y ** (1/100)` so you have to compute a root of 100th power, 100 is *even value* and you have a *complex result* (x ** (1/3), x** (1/5) ... x ** (1/101) should return negative values while x **(1/2) ... x ** (1/100) are complex)

Comment: Oh, tricky. It appears prefix `-` is treated as unary operator with rather low precedence, not as part of the literal. That's also the problem in the Python REPL.

Comment: It might be worth noting that using `np.power` or `**` with float arguments  does not allow the returned array to have a complex datatype - it will still have a float datatype. Hence the reason for the `nan` values (you can verify this by looking at `np.power.types`).

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far! Has anyone got an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply start off with a complex datatype:

```
ar = np.array([-0.3700708 , -0.41282227, -0.25959961], dtype=np.complex)
>>> np.power(ar, 2.01)
array([ 0.13553084+0.00425923j,  0.16883773+0.00530594j,
        0.06645639+0.00208848j])
```

Which will give you the complex result.
And e.g. take the absolute value afterwards:

```
>>> np.abs(np.power(ar, 2.01))
array([ 0.13559775,  0.16892109,  0.0664892 ])
```

Or pick the real part:

```
>>> np.real(np.power(ar, 2.01))
array([ 0.13553084,  0.16883773,  0.06645639])
```